# Ant - How to direct where files are saved to

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins

In my build.xml file, I am able to search multiple folders for .jmx files which i then use in jmeter. I then want to save the output files, which are .jtl files in one folder in a different location. However they are being saved in the same folder structure as the jmx files are being read from.

So for example I have jmx files in a root folder called JTesting, which two folders inside that called basket and customer. Within each of these folders, there is a folder called jmxFiles which contains the .jmx files. So the path looks like this:

JTesting/basket/jmxFiles   &
JTetsing/Customer/jmxFiles

My ant file pulls these files out fine, but when saving the .jtl files, I want it to be store in a results/jtl folder structure, but instead it saves it as:

results/jtl/basket/jmxFiles        &
results/jtl/customer/jmxFiles

So it adds the folder structure from where it got the files. My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="all">
  <!-- Define an environment variable pointing to JMETER folder or change this -->
  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
  <property name="jmeter-home" location="${env.JMETER_DIR}"/>
  <!-- ant-jmeter.jar comes with jmeter, be sure this is the release you have -->
  <path id="ant.jmeter.classpath">
    <pathelement
       location="${jmeter-home}/extras/ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar" />
  </path>
  <taskdef
    name="jmeter"
    classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"
    classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath" />

    <!-- TODO: Change this so it deletes results folders and re-creates them -->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="results"/>
    <delete file="jmeter.log"/>
    <mkdir dir="results/jtl"/>
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="clean">
    <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${jmeter-home}"
       resultlogdir="results/jtl">
      <testplans dir="JTesting" includes="/**/**/*.jmx"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
      <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
      <property name="testData.fullPath" value="C:/TestData"/>
    </jmeter>
  </target>

  <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter-home}/lib"/>

    <!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
    <path id="xslt.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
    </path>

  <!-- This is not needed for the plugin, but it produces a nice html report
       which can be saved usin hudson's archive artifact feature -->
  <target name="report" depends="test">
    <xslt
       classpathref="xslt.classpath"
       basedir="results/jtl"
       destdir="results/html"
       includes="*.jtl"
       style="${jmeter-home}/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"/>
  </target>
  <target name="all" depends="test, report"/>
</project>
```

How can i get all the .jtl files to be store in results/jtl???

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a maven plugin for doing common file system operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061771/is-there-a-maven-plugin-for-doing-common-file-system-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Use the a combination of the following two tasks:

- [TempFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html)
- [Copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

And if you need to create a new file rather than move an existing file, use the following task:

- [Replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html)

**References**

- [Velocity DVSL Ant Task Reference](https://velocity.apache.org/dvsl/1.0/ant_task_reference.html)
- [Ant Core Task Quick Reference (pdf)](http://www.mobilefish.com/download/ant/AntCoreRef.pdf)